# How to watch what's happening to the global array's while debugging inside function in c++?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I just wanted to see how `subTree` array is changing while i am iterating over `dfs()` function.

[image]

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define w(x)            int x; cin>>x; while(x--)
#define nl              "\n"
#define fr(i,t)         for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
#define fr1(i,a,b)      for(int i = a; i<b; i++)
#define frr(i,n)        for(int i = n; i>=0; i--)
#define frr1(i,a,b)     for(int i = a; i>=b; i--)
#define dbug(x)         cout<<#x<<"="<<x<<endl;
#define fast            ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);cout.tie(NULL);
#define pb              push_back
// int                      -10**9  to 10**9        4 byte       -2**31 to +2**31    -2147483647 to +2147483648
// long long int            -10**19 to 10**19       8 byte       -2**63 to +2**63
// unsigned long long int   -0      to 10**20       8 byte          0   to +2**64
// INT_MAX                  0x7fffffff 2147483647
const int M1  = 1000000007;
const int M2  = 998244353;
const int N = 100005;
vector<int> g[N];
int subTree[N];
bool vis[N];

int dfs(int u){
    vis[u] = true;
    if(g[u].size() == 1){ // Leaf Node
        subTree[u] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    for(auto &v: g[u]){
        if(!vis[v])     subTree[u] += dfs(v);
    }
    return ++subTree[u];
}


int main(){
    fast;
    int n,m,k,a,b,temp;                                          
    cin>>n>>m;
    fr(i,m){
        cin>>a>>b;
        g[a].pb(b);
        g[b].pb(a);
    }
    dfs(1);
    fr1(i,1,8){
        cout<<subTree[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good fit for this site. While the question is valid, it's more about how to use your specific editor + debugger. The answer for gdb would be different, as would QtCreator, etc.. hence, voting to close

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem But there are many people who uses cpp in vscode and at some point they've also reached to this point and they know how to resolve it. I am just asking for help. Please explain why this question is not fit for this site or tell me if this problem is very very specific that only 5 people in this world knows the answer.

Comment: I know there's plenty of ppl using VSC, and I'm not saying this isn't a legitimate question to have. This site, though, is about problems specifically with code. Trying to solve a problem, and not knowing exactly how to write the code, or having a weird bug, and not being able to find the problem. You're more asking  how to use a tool to help. That's fine, but maybe there are other platforms/sites/resources specifically about debug tools. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic this question is about the software, not the code. That's why I voted to close. Best wishes

Comment: PS: I've only used VSCode for a couple of hours all together, but I think you can add a global variable to your watch list, and perhaps keep an eye on it there? That's just my guess, but who knows, it could help

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks for the first time being helpful. I'll check.

Answer (score 2):

> " ... how to watch whats happening ..."

Whenever my understanding of gdb falls short, I do not hesitate to add a (probably temporary) viewing mechanism to cout useful 'state-info'.

Consider:

1. add a "std::stringstream ssDbg;" above  " int dfs(int u) ", but in scope,
2. add one or more statements (inside of dfs) to contribute information to ssDbg.  They each have the form

   "ssDbg << " [... usefull status info ...] " << endl" .
3. set a breakpoint (or maybe 2) inside of dfs(int).

then, when you want to inspect the behavior as reflected in the ssDbg contents

4. add one (or maybe 2) small 'c-style' functions to show whats up.   I use a c-style function (i.e. not a class function attribute)  because gdb handles c-style-functions better and are easier to invoke. Yes, c-style can access your class, and you can even declare these support functions a friend.

4.a) Your functions will at least display what has been captured, i.e.

```
void coutCapture() { cout << ssDbg.str() << endl; }; "
```

4.b) Your functions might display other current state info (i.e. do not limit your outputs to just the capture contents.)

4.c You might want each coutCapture() display effort to also clear and reset the ssDbg,

4.d  or you might want a separate ssClr() to let the contents build.

I use the following:

```
  void ssClr(stringstream& ss) { ss.str(string()); ss.clear(); }
  //                             clear data        clear flags
```

Summary: "coutCapture()" and the "ssDbg << ..." instrumentation are augmenting gdb in a customized way.  I usually find gdb sufficient.

I developed this technique on embedded systems, because of various and sometimes unique limitations.

---

Also, be sure to review gdb documentation... every time I look I find more things to try.

Comment: On Linux, It is easy to open another window and output 'live' output there (so that normal operational displays are not distorted).

Comment: On a desktop, I would imagine there would be opportunity to invoke the coutCapture() show mechanism at a particular time within the normal operation.

Comment: `#define dbug(x)         cout<<#x<<"="<<x<<endl;` your answer is long version of writing this statement `dbug(x)` everywhere tell me if i am wrong.  but in my case i want to watch each array live in the debug console as i iterate over the code. I have realized that it is not possible in c++. Although if you've ever done debugging in python on vscode, you've noticed that debugging is live and all the variable whether it is local or global are available to watch live and see how they're affecting.

Comment: The embedded systems I worked on had no attached equipment appropriate for any stream, only ethernet to gdb.  Furthermore, the systems had up to 1000 threads running.  Sharing a stream (such as cout) was simply not feasible. So, no, my suggestion was not a long form of what you suggest.  On my Linux desktop it is trivial to launch a 'terminal' and open an fstream connect to it thru the file system.  If that is your environment, than certainly you _can_ run (closer to real time) with what you have suggested.